# Highlight selected node from managed bean in primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a requirement that I have to highlight a newly added node in the tree to some different color. I'm using JSF2 and Primefaces tree component. I'm trying something like this:-

In Managed Bean,

```
getSelectedNode().setStyleClass("ui-helper-clearfix ui-tree-node-content ui-corner-all ui-tree-selectable-node ui-state-highlight");
```

In xhtml,

```
<p:treeNode id="privilegesTreeNode" styleClass="#{privilegesTreeBean.selectedNode.styleClass}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{node}" id="lblNode" />
                    </p:treeNode>
```

But this css is applied on all nodes..not the selected node..then I thought of may be filling on some condition, I tried this:-

```
<p:treeNode id="privilegesTreeNode" styleClass="#{privilegesTreeBean.selectedNode.styleClass ne '' ? privilegesTreeBean.selectedNode.styleClass : ''}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{node}" id="lblNode" />
                    </p:treeNode>
```

Can anyone help me as I'm stuck in this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea with the condition works fine for me, e.g.

```
<h:outputText style="#{node.name == 'NEW NODE' ? 'background-color: yellow;' : 'background-color: none;'}" value="#{node}" />
```

Comment: @KBProdigy what if i have to do multiple checks how do i go about that?
i.e. in the answer above if the node could be shown in 3 different colors (red, yellow and green) depending on the value of the "node.name" then how do i go about it (maybe invoke a javascript call to perform the check and highlight the node??